# Speed of native R function vs C++ equivalent

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

When I compare the speed of the native Gamma function `gamma` in R to the C++ equivalent `std::tgamma` I find that the latter is about 10-15x slower. Why? I expect some differences, but this is huge, isn't it?

My implementation:

```
library("Rcpp")
library("microbenchmark")

cppFunction("
     double gammacpp(double x) {
         return(std::tgamma(x));
     }
")

x = max(0, rnorm(1, 50, 25))
microbenchmark(gamma(x), gammacpp(x))
```

Results on my machine:

```
Unit: nanoseconds
expr         min   lq    mean median uq  max neval cld
gamma(x)    100   101  124.91  101  102 1001   100   a
gammacpp(x) 1000 1101 1302.98 1200 1300 9401   100   b
```

Comment: I highly recommend you submit this question to the creators of the R compiler or interpreter.  The "why" questions should be submitted to the proper authorities.

Comment: How did you account for the overhead of R calling into the `C++` function ? For all we know this could all be R-side overhead.

Comment: What's the time like if you call `std::tgamma` in a native C++ program?

Comment: Did you compile your C++ program with compiler optimizations enabled (usually not the default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the code of `gamma()` (for example by typing `gamma<Return>`): it just calls a primitive.

Your `Rcpp` function is set up to be *convenient*.  All it took was a two-liner.  But it has *some* overhead is saving the state of the random-number generator, setting up the `try`/`catch` block for exception handling and more.  We have documented how you can skip *some* of these steps, but in many cases that is ill-advised.

In a nutshell, my view is that you have a poorly chosen comparison: too little happens in the functions you benchmark.  Also note the unit: nanoseconds.  You have a lot of measurement error here.

But the morale is that with a 'naive' (and convenient) C++ function as the one you wrote as a one-liner,  you will not beat somewhat optimised and tuned and *already compiled* code from inside R.  That is actually a good thing because if you did, you would have to now rewrite large chunks of R .

*Edit:* For kicks, here is a third variant 'in the middle' where we use `Rcpp` to call the same C API of R.

##### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double gammaStd(double x) { return (std::tgamma(x)); }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector gamma_R(Rcpp::NumericVector x) { return (Rcpp::gamma(x)); }

/*** R
set.seed(123)
x <- max(0, rnorm(1, 50, 25))
res <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(R = gamma(x), Cpp = gammaStd(x), Sugar = gamma_R(x) )
res
*/
```

##### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/72383007/answer.cpp")
> set.seed(123)
> x <- max(0, rnorm(1, 50, 25))
> res <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(R = gamma(x), Cpp = gammaStd(x), Sugar = gamma_R(x) )
> 
res
Unit: nanoseconds
  expr  min     lq     mean median     uq     max neval cld
     R  102  112.0   136.95    124  134.5    1068   100   a
   Cpp 1111 1155.5 11930.02   1186 1260.0 1054813   100   a
 Sugar 1142 1201.0  6355.92   1246 1301.5  506628   100   a
>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! You say that I will not beat the optimized and already compiled R code. Isn't the C++ implementation also heavily optimized? I thought that the observed speed difference was mainly due to overhead and optimization, but I assumed that the latter was negligible.

Comment: The nice thing about being able to _measure_ and _benchmark_ is that we can validate our assumptions---or disprove them.